# How can you increase similarity in Google image search?

Tags: google-image-search

In Google you can image search, which will return images which are visually similar to the image you searched for.

How can I increase how similar the returned results are?

Comment: adding additional search words will help, or use a reverse image search to find other copies of the same image https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1325808?hl=en

Comment: @Mousey that link is how to search for visually similar images as I've mentioned in the question. I'm asking however how I can increase how similar the images returned are.

Comment: adding extra keywords to describe the image is the only way

Comment: @Mousey that doesn't really increase the visual similarity though, so I guess there's no way

Comment: I've not found another way but would be interested if there was, adding a search word describing the image is the closest I've got.